# storing data into table using loops

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

This is for a project asking multiple choice questions to the user.

There are 5 tables:

1. table quiz to store the quiz id
2. table question which store question and id
3. table answer that store list of answer
4. table result which store id user and quiz
5. table result_detail which store result id and answer from user

I managed to load the question and answers. I am also able to store data into a result table but I failed to store the answer from the user. What i want is when the user chooses the radiobutton, the ID of the answer is passed to the result_detail table

Here's the code:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Or RadioButton2.Checked = True Or RadioButton3.Checked = True Or RadioButton4.Checked = True Then
        If Nombor.Text = 10 Then
            Response.Redirect("EndQues.aspx")
        Else
            Nombor.Text = Val(Nombor.Text) + 1
            Counter += 1
            question()
            clean()
        End If

    Else

        MsgBox("Error", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
    End If

End Sub

Sub question()
conn.Open()

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From view_question Where QuestionID=@IdSoalan", conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdSoalan", Counter)
    Dim dr1 As SqlDataReader
    dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If dr1.Read() Then
        Me.lblquest.Text = dr1("QuestionTxt")
        Me.RadioButton1.Text = dr1("1")
        Me.RadioButton2.Text = dr1("2")
        Me.RadioButton3.Text = dr1("3")
        Me.RadioButton4.Text = dr1("4")


    Else
        conn.Close()
        Counter += 1
        question
    End If
    conn.Close()
End Sub


Sub clean()
    RadioButton1.Checked = False
    RadioButton2.Checked = False
    RadioButton3.Checked = False
    RadioButton4.Checked = False
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    question()
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("Insert into TblResult (Result_Quiz_Id,Result_NoMatric,) values (1,'" & Session("NoMatrik") & "')", conn)
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: "failed to store the answer from the user" can you be more specific? Where is the code that does this and what is doing? throwing an error or not changing values as expected?

Comment: when the user checked one of the radiobutton, the id of the answer should be inserted into table_resultdetail together with the new autogenerated id created during pageload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I understand here is that you want selected radio buttons to have an ID equivalent of the answer right? My solution to this is to store the ID into an **Array** of 4 elements everytime you will add radiobutton text.

```
Me.RadioButton1.Text = dr1("1")
myArr(0) = dr1("id_1")
Me.RadioButton2.Text = dr1("2")
myArr(1) = dr1("id_2")
Me.RadioButton3.Text = dr1("3")
myArr(2) = dr1("id_3")
Me.RadioButton4.Text = dr1("4")
myArr(3) = dr1("id_4")
```

Then everytime that you will save it, just put conditions to identify selected radiobutton.

```
If Me.RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
     answerID = myArr(0)
```

And so on. There is another way but try this first if this is the process that you need.

Comment: i have problem in inserting answerId into table.the error is Input string was not in a correct format- Conversion from string "Table" to type 'Integer' is not valid